# Codeigniter and WAMP Routing Issue - What am I missing?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

I'm scratching my head for almost two days now, thought some expert advice can help me here.

I got a CodeIgniter application I need to maintain (version 2.X), and this is my first experience with it. The structure of the application is:

```
myApp
    application
        cache
        certs
        config
        controllers
        ...
        modules
            moduleA
                controllers
                models
                views
            moduleB
                controllers
                models
                views
            ...
        third_party
        views
    cgi-bin
    ...
    system
    themes
    uploads
```

I installed WAMP, and throw the entire myApp under c:\wamp\www. Another steps I did:

1) Changed the 'listen' port of the Apache since I also run IIS on my machine.

2) Enabled the Apache rewrite module.

3) Set the 'all' and 'all granted' in the `<Directory .../>` section:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride all

    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

4) Set correctly the database name in the 'database.php' config.

5) Verified .htaccess file is located under myApp folder, and the content of the .htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

6) In 'routes.config' the default controller is: $route['default_controller'] = "login";

With these steps I was able to host this application locally and work for a while. But, I had to change my Windows user password, and after rebooting my computer I receive 404 errors all of a sudden.

I am able to browse to the 'login' page via http://localhost:port/myApp/index.php (or just http://localhost:port/myApp), but from there I receive only 404 error messages. I can browse with the full url though:

http://localhost:port/mpApp/index.php/login/forgotpassword - Accessible
http://localhost:port/myApp/login/forgotpassword - 404 error

Now, I am not sure whether it's related to my Windows user password change, but this issue became a voodoo, since I swear I could work and browse locally to **all** pages. I also reinstalled WAMP twice and repeated
the process above just to make sure I'm doing things right.

Can anyone think of something I am missing here?

Comment: Did you download HMVC straight from here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc this is now only for Codeigniter 3 when you go to the download >  branches you will be able to see version

Comment: Try with added `RewriteBase /myApp/`, maybe also question mark here `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`.

Comment: @Tpojka, thank you for the comment - still not working for me.

Comment: @wolfgang1983, not sure regrading this one. I can definitely see that HMVC is used in the application, though the CI version is 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, at least the one worked for me:

In config.php (under ...myApp\application\config) I changed the value of $config['uri_protocol'] from 'AUTO' to 'PATH_INFO'.

Comment: if I mass search for uri_protocol in the whole ci4 folder no results are found in any of the files

Answer (score 0):

Step 1
Add or set htaccess file to this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Step 2
Change config['uri_protocol'] = 'URI_REQUEST' to 'PATH_INFO'

Thats worked for my CI3